# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '[root]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am working on spring boot  and using mysql through jpa but while running the app I am facing issue

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.6.3)[0;39m

[2m2022-02-10 14:23:29.855[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mC.CourseCollectionApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting CourseCollectionApplication using Java 16.0.2 on DESKTOP-MRV2CPP with PID 3388 (C:\Users\hp\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.11.1.RELEASE\CourseCollection\target\classes started by hp in C:\Users\hp\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.11.1.RELEASE\CourseCollection)
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:29.857[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mC.CourseCollectionApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:30.365[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:30.406[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 33 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:30.832[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:30.842[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:30.842[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:30.944[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:30.944[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1044 ms
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:31.115[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:31.181[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:31.347[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:31.453[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.807[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at CourseCollection.CourseCollectionApplication.main(CourseCollectionApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.810[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at CourseCollection.CourseCollectionApplication.main(CourseCollectionApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.851[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.945[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: No identifier specified for entity: CourseCollection.entities.Course
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.945[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: CourseCollection.entities.Course
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.948[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.958[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2022-02-10 14:23:32.973[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: CourseCollection.entities.Course
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at CourseCollection.CourseCollectionApplication.main(CourseCollectionApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: CourseCollection.entities.Course
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:771) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

this is application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coursecollection?servertimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Clgprj@
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

the pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>CourseCollection</groupId>
    <artifactId>CourseCollection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CourseCollection</name>
    <description>course library</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have gone through the existing answers on stack overflow but it was not helpful to me. I have also checked whether it has any extra spaces after or before the username and password.
screenshot of the database is
[image]

Course class is given below

```
package CourseCollection.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class Course {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    
    public Course(long id, String title, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public Course() {
        super();
        id=0;
        title="";
        description="";
    }
...
...
...
```

Comment: Can you please show me your entity with import package?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I have added the starting code of Course class with import packages

Answer (score 0):

Do you have annotations in your Course entity?
Because it is complaining about that as well in your exception

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
```

Also, don't forget a no-arg constructor.

Comment: I have made the changes but still that access denied error is coming.

Comment: Can you please update your stacktrace and share an image of your database as well? It is possible you either made a typo in your database name, or your mysql service is not working. Please update your question

Comment: I have updated the stacktrace and also added an image of database workbench